# How to make a clearColor for superview on iOS 8

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios8, modalviewcontroller

Help please. How to make a clear Color for modal View on iOS 8, write so

`self.view.superview.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];`

Work on iOS 7 but not on iOS 8. It becomes clear but not completely

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try to change the alpha value like that :-

```
[[UIColor clearColor] colorWithAlphaComponent:0.6];
```

Comment: Yes, and there clear color. View can be transparent but superview is not.

Comment: self.view.superview = nil; Error - Assignment to readonly property

Comment: ok so it is not allowing, but can you try setting the your subview size equivalent to superview.

Answer (score 0):

If you set background color for the main UIViewController view, you need to setup it before:

```
- (void)setupModalPresentationStyle
{
    self.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleCrossDissolve;
    if (SYSTEM_VERSION_GREATER_THAN_OR_EQUAL_TO(@"8.0")) {
        self.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationOverFullScreen;
    }
}

- (void)awakeFromNib
{
    [super awakeFromNib];
    [self setupModalPresentationStyle];
}
```

And when you present this UIViewController, you need to setup current presenting UIViewController:

```
- (void)doneButtonTap:(id)sender {
    self.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationCurrentContext;
    [self presentViewController:detailsViewController animated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

Comment: Where to write this code? self.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationCurrentContext;
    [self presentViewController:detailsViewController animated:YES completion:nil];

Comment: somewhere, where you present your modal view controller